# Firebase Database not storing users information

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For some reason, nothing gets stored into the database, I've been using this same code and it worked before I don't understand why it's not working now

this is how have been doing it:

```
//auth process above
                    ProgressHUD.showSuccess()
                    let when = DispatchTime.now() + 1
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when){
                        ProgressHUD.dismiss()
                        self.storeUserData(userId: (user?.user.uid)!) //original was (user?.uid)! but it seems that google has change it
                        KeychainWrapper.standard.set((user?.user.uid)!, forKey: "uid")
                        let TBVC = mainTabBarController()
                        self.present(TBVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }

    func storeUserData(userId: String) {
        Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userId).setValue([
            "username": username.text,
            "password": password.text,
            "email": email.text
            ])
    }
```

Comment: Did you set up the database? You need to do that now (but didn't in the past, Firebase changed this recently). If you have a new project you need to setup rules etc. before writing to database or storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this with completion to see the error

```
let dic = [
        "username": username.text,
        "password": password.text,
        "email": email.text
        ]

Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userId).setValue(dic, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in

     print(error) // check error and see
 })
```

Comment: I see I'm getting a permission denied